# The origin of 首にする

Tags: etymology, idioms

I've come across an interesting idiom in the following sentence:

> もしも私が社長だったら、あの人**を首にする**と思います。
> If I were the company president, I would fire that person.

What is the origin of the idiom 首にする?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm an etymology geek -- I love finding out how and when different words and expressions and meanings arose.  I offer this as an addition to @[sundowner](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/45489/)'s fine [answer post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/101419/5229).

> What is the origin of the idiom 首にする?

Let's look first at the meanings of 首【くび】.  My source is the 日本国語大辞典【にほんこくごだいじてん】 (NKD), basically like the OED only for Japanese.  A somewhat abridged version of this dictionary is offered free of charge via the Kotobank resource aggregator website (in Japanese): https://kotobank.jp/

#### 首【くび】 meanings

The NKD entry at Kotobank is [here](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%A6%96%E3%83%BB%E9%A0%B8-2032217).  From that, we learn that 首【くび】 first referred to the *"neck"*, the part of the body along the spine where the torso narrows and connects to the head.  This sense is first cited to the [日本書紀【にほんしょき】](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nihon_Shoki) of 720, basically around the earliest horizon of any longer texts written in the Japanese language.

Later on, in the late 900s, the word 首【くび】 is cited to mean *"the part of the body from the neck upwards"*, basically synonymous with *"head"*.

Then some 800+ years after that, around 1800, we get a citation of the term used to mean *"one's end, specifically with regard to the end of one's relation or connection to someone else"*, apparently as an extension from the idea of *"beheading: losing one's head"*.

Consider the development of senses for the English word *"head"*, as used in expressions like *"it will be your head!"* -- we see a similar shift from a literal sense of "the topmost body part", to a reference to losing that body part (and dying), to figurative senses of being fired.

#### The phrase 首【くび】にする

The NKD entry for this is [here](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%A6%96%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-251407).  The first citation we see is from 1802, just two years after we see 首【くび】 on its own used to refer to the end of a connection.

The ～にする construction is pretty straightforward: this means *"do something into ~, make something into ~, treat something as ~"*, so the combination of 首【くび】 *"one's end"* + にする produces the expected meaning of *"to bring someone to their end, to end someone, with regard to a relation or connection"*.

Answer (score 2):

First note that there is another expression (Aの)首を切る, which means the same as (Aを)首にする.

The most relevant expression in English should be *head count* although I think it is used mostly for hiring. The idea should be just the same, cutting off heads means reducing the number of people.

More precisely, there is a jukugo [馘首{かくしゅ}](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%A6%98%E9%A6%96-460314) meaning *to fire*.  According to web searches 馘首 was read くび conventionally, hence 馘首{くび}になる meant *to get fired*. (I think still [馘](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%A6%98%28%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97%29-2785202)になる is sometimes used. Strictly speaking, 首にする/なる is a misusage of 首, albeit totally common.)

Comment: FWIW, English phrase _"head count"_ simply means ["the number of people"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/head_count), usually in reference to a group of some kind.